# Adding a category history to a post in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a problem I can't deal with.

Let's assume that we have following categories:

- Main

  - Some category
  - Some other category
  - And one more

How to show then something like Main > Some category in a Wordpress single post. To make a hierarchy. I want post to be under "Some category", not under "Main", but to list main. Is that possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. By not by use of typical get_posts() with parent category id
You can use get_terms($taxonomies) to have an array post id's by chosen criteria(for ex. parent=0) , then use wp_query() to display them (or list). 
Look at [get_terms in wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)